# Fetch product first based on values in column laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this query that fetches properties from table

```
$properties = Property::with('Category')
            ->orderBy('name','asc')
            ->where('status','Active')
            ->get();
```

In my table i have added new column `featured` it's value is either `0` or `1`. I want to show property with `1`  value in featured column first

Please suggest solution Thanks.

Comment: Two questions:
1. Where did you add the featured column? Inside the `Property` table or `Category`table? 
2. Why are you refering to `products`? Did you mean `property`?

Comment: @Veenz featured column is added inside property table, yes it is property

Comment: What happens if you had another where clause before the ->get(); method? Something like ->where('featured', 1);

Comment: @Veenz this will not work because it will show only featured properties

Comment: Since the featured are `int` you can just use `orderBy('feature','desc')`

Comment: Try ->where('properties.status','=',''Active')->where('properties.featured','=',1)

Answer (score 0):

The featured column appears to be an `int`, so you can use `orderBy()`, for example:

```
$properties = Property::with('Category')
            ->orderBy('name','asc')
            ->orderBy('featured','desc')
            ->where('status','Active')
            ->get();
```

The above would order the `properties` by column `featured`, which in your question would only be `1` or `0`.

---

Make sure that your use `orderBy('featured', 'desc')` after any other `orderBy()` to ensure that it gets the featured `properties` first.